# how to update the multiple rows at a time in aspnetboilerplate?

Tags: sql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, aspnetboilerplate

I want to execute the SQL clause like:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
WHERE condition;
```

Because I want to update multiple rows in database. But I don't know how to implement this.

Comment: If the `condition` is wide enough, then you will automatically update more than one record.

Comment: You can use  install the Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Bulk and use `BulkUpdateAsync` . Or use EFCore.BulkExtensions

Comment: OK, I will try, thanks@viveknuna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. Using the extension method `GetDbContext` of `Repository` to get the `DbContext`, then using the `DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync` to execute raw SQL.

Comment: you can take a look to this article (for stored procedures)  https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Articles/Using-Stored-Procedures,-User-Defined-Functions-and-Views/index.html